# RTF file to attributed string

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring, ios7.1

I'm trying to read RTF file contents to attributed string, but `attributedText` is `nil`. Why?

```
if let fileURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(filename, withExtension: "rtf") {
    var error: NSError?
    if let attributedText = NSAttributedString(fileURL: fileURL, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSRTFDTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil, error: &error){
        textView.attributedText = attributedText
    }
}
```

**Upd**.: I changed code to:

```
if let fileURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(filename, withExtension: "rtf") {
    var error: NSError?

    let attributedText = NSAttributedString(fileURL: fileURL, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSRTFTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil, error: &error)
        println(error?.localizedDescription)


        textView.attributedText = attributedText

}
```

Now there is crash on `textView.attributedText = attributedText` says: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. I see in debugger that `attributedText` is non nil and contains text with attributes from file.

Comment: What does say the `error`?

Comment: @Larme I can't read the error due to the scope is not executing.

Comment: Don't do the `if`, just do `let attributedText`, and the read the `error`.

Comment: @Larme ```Optional("The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)")```

Comment: @Larme thanks, I got it. ```NSRTFDTextDocumentType``` should be ```NSRTFTextDocumentType```

Comment: @Larme now I have a crash with unwrapping value in textView. Can you please help me?

Comment: I don't speak Swift. So I can't help you with all the unwrapping nil value stuff.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rather than looking to see if the operation worked/failed in the debugger, you’d be much better off writing the code to handle the failure appropriately:

```
if let attributedText = NSAttributedString(fileURL: fileURL, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSRTFTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil, error: &error) {
    textView.attributedText = attributedText
}
else if let error = error {                
    println(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

**Swift 4**

```
do {
    let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(url: fileURL, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.rtf], documentAttributes: nil)
} catch {
    print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Comment: There is still crash on ```Optional("The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)")```. Error is nil.

Comment: If you have the exact code I put above, I can’t see how error can be nil given the error you give is non-nil (and if it’s nil, where is your error message coming from?).  Are you sure the crash isn’t elsewhere in your code?

Comment: you were right. The problem was I used didSet to set text. Replacing code to viewDidLoad solved the problem.

Comment: How can i get the text of odt file?

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4** @available(iOS 7.0, *)

```
func loadRTF(from resource: String) -> NSAttributedString? {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: resource, withExtension: "rtf") else { return nil }

    guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else { return nil }

    return try? NSAttributedString(data: data,
                                   options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.rtf],
                                   documentAttributes: nil)
}
```

Usage:

```
textView.attributedText = loadRTF(from: "FILE_HERE_WITHOUT_RTF")
```

Comment: **Swift 4** Update
`options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.rtf]`